# CSS rgba background color loading before opacity

Tags: css

I have an image taking up the whole viewport. Over top of it is a div, also taking up the whole viewport. The div has `background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);` to make the image behind it look darker. It works great, except that when the page is loading, the whole screen is covered with gray before opacity is applied and I can see the image underneath.

Is there any way to make the image and the div (with opacity applied) appear at the same time? I don't want to see the big block of gray while the page is loading.

Comment: well, you could use JavaScript to add a class based on the image load event, but why bother? why not just adjust your image directly?

Comment: The image is rather large and is used in other parts of the page, so I was hoping to minimize page loading time by having only one image instead of two. But it looks like I may have no choice. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it for you https://jsfiddle.net/c259LrpL/26/

This will wait till images are loaded then make the `img` and the `div` visible at the same time... I think

```
<img id="img1" src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/sports/1/"  style="visibility: hidden" >
<div id="over" style="visibility: hidden" > 

</div>
<script>
  $(window).on("load", function() {
    $("#img1").css("visibility", "visible");
    $("#over").css("visibility", "visible");
  }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider this idea. We'll use the `:after` pseudoclass of the `<img>` container's background property (the `<figure>` in my example) to control the darkening. When the page is fully loaded, we add a `.loaded` class to the `body`. This does 2 things simultaneously:

1. Transition the opacity from 0 to 1 on the `<figure>`
2. Transition the semi-opaque background from (0, 0, 0, 0.5) to transparent

```js
window.onload = init;

function init() {
  document.body.classList.add("loaded");
}
```

```css
body,
figure{
  margin: 0;
}

figure {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 2s opacity; 
}

img {
  width: 100vw;
}

figure:after {
  transition: 2s background;
  background: transparent;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.loaded figure:after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.loaded figure {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1432637194732-34cedd856522?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&w=1080&fit=max&s=a135be75b0fa480c18b22b5e557f56b3" alt="">      
</figure>
```

http://codepen.io/antibland/pen/EKrVKr

Comment: The `DOMContentLoaded` event does not wait for stylesheets, images, and subframes to be loaded before the event fires. `load` does.

Comment: Good call. Changed that in my example.

Comment: It seems that the darkening is fading out, instead of fading in? It's dark at first, and then it lightens as it fades in.

Comment: @jessica It's your lucky day. Check out the updated code and demo.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can wait until the browser is done loading all images and then slowly change the opacity, like a fade-in effect. Here's a preview:

```js
var imageElement = document.getElementById('image');
var overlayElement = document.getElementById('overlay');
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  imageElement.style.opacity = "1";
  overlayElement.style.opacity = "1";
}, false);
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
}
#image,
#overlay {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 800px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out;
}
#overlay {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<img id="image" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3d/LARGE_elevation.jpg">
<div id="overlay"></div>
```

It's plain javascript. I know the tag only said css, but what you want is not possible with css only. I quickly created an overlay effect, don't mind the css except for: `opacity: 0;` and `transition: all 2s ease-in-out; -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in-out` for the fade-in effect.

The javascript works like this: I create 2 variables which get the elements from the DOM. The image has an ID `image` and the overlay has an ID `overlay`. Next we set an eventlistener to our window. When the window is completely loaded, it should execute everything in the function. The opacities of both the image and overlay are set to `1` (visible). With our css property `transition` we manage the fade-in effect.

Comment: Thank you, but it's now what I'm going for - I want the image to simply appear darker. :)